# How to save my aggregates results into an external variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

First of all , I am creating an application with a calendar date picker . You can select an appointment for the day you want . From there , everything went well. Now I need to add a limit to 4 appointment per day.. I am using node/express with mongoDB. I am using aggregate which returns how many times the date is in the database, then I would like to save that results into an external variable to add condition. This is my code so far :

```
var count;
var limit;

Date.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match:
            {
                "date": "2020-11-20"
            }
        },
        {
            $group:
            {
                _id: null,
                currentOrder: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        }
    ], (err, res) => {
        count = res;
        if (count === []) {
            console.log('empty')
        } else {

            console.log("This is count : ", count[0].currentOrder)
            limit = count[0].currentOrder
        }
    }
)

console.log('This is limit: ', limit)
console.log('This is count outside of aggregate: ', count)


if (limit === 4) {
    try {
        const savedDate = await disabledDate.save();
        res.json(savedDate)
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err })
    }
}
```

So with this , in the console I get : 
***This is limit:  undefined 

This is count :  2  

This is count outside of aggregate:  undefined***

So basically , I just want to use that "count" results , to use a condition to execute a certain code which will disable that date.. Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap aggregate in async function, because "aggregate" seems to be asynchronous.

```
(async function() {
    await Date.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match:
            {
                "date": "2020-11-20"
            }
        },
        {
            $group:
            {
                _id: null,
                currentOrder: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        }
    ], (err, res) => {
        count = res;
        if (count === []) {
            console.log('empty')
        } else {

            console.log("This is count : ", count[0].currentOrder)
            limit = count[0].currentOrder
        }
    }
)
  })();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! It was not working, but you put me on the right track to find my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out ! If anyone has the same problem and is trying to achieve what I am doing , this is what I did :

```
var count;
var limit;

Date.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match:
            {
                "date": req.body.date.slice(0, 10)
            }
        },
        {
            $group:
            {
                _id: null,
                currentOrder: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        }
    ], (err, res) => {
        count = res;
        if (count === []) {
            console.log('empty')
        } else {
            setDate(count[0].currentOrder)
            console.log("This is count : ", count[0].currentOrder)
            limit = count[0].currentOrder
        }
    }
)

async function setDate(limit) {
    if (limit >= 4) {
        try {
            const savedDate = await disabledDate.save();
            res.json(savedDate)
        } catch (err) {
            res.json({ message: err })
        }
    }
}
```

I made an async function to handle the change , then I called it inside the callback and it worked !